# Git: apply some (but not all) changes to work tree upon branch checkout/switch

Tags: git

Is it possible to tell Git to apply all changes to the work tree on branch switch/checkout, *except* when the change constitutes a file deletion?

Consider a Git repo in which branch `branchA` contains the files `foo` and `bar`, but `branchB` does not.

Under normal circumstances, if I am on `branchA`, when I `git switch branchB` or `git checkout branchB` the files `foo` and `bar` will be deleted from my work tree.

In this example, after switching branches, I want `foo` and `bar` to be listed as "untracked" in `git status` output, while keeping the files untouched in the work tree. All other changes (modifications, renames, additions) should be applied to the work tree as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need to do in this case is get them from branchA because normal flow *orders* to have them removed.

```
git checkout branchA -- foo bar
git reset foo bar
```

Comment: That's unfortunate. At least this can be scripted with `diff --name-status`.

Comment: It is not unfortunate. you are asking for git to behave in a way that is exceptional (who would _normally_ want to see files from the branch that they were on if they move to a branch or revision that doesn't have those files?)..... and it can be done (as I just showed), just can't be done straight when checking out into `branchB`.